# Using Object Manager To Load & Manage Custom Modules ( OOP )

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, oop, module

*Hey Guys,*

i'm trying to develop an application and because of the
requirements of the software, i want to use an object
manager to manage my custom modules. Unfortunately, i
have a few problems, i hope you can help me with.

The object manager is loaded once as 'Self.OM' :

```
from OM import *

class VTE:

    def __init__( Self ):
    
        Self.OM = OM( )
        CFG = Self.OM.Load_Module( 'Config' )
```

The aim is to successfully load the 'Config' file via the Object Manager.

---

The 'OM.py' file looks like this:

```
class OM :
    
    Registered_Modules = { }
    
    def __init__( Self , Module = '' , Debug_Mode = False ) :
       
        Self.Debug_Mode = Debug_Mode
        Self.Registered_Modules = OM.Registered_Modules
        
        print( f"Debug Mode : {Debug_Mode}" )
```

---

The variable 'Registered_Modules = { }' is defined globally so that
it is available in every part of the application.

Then I define the variable as 'Self.Registered_Modules' :
Self.Registered_Modules = OM.Registered_Modules

Then the 'Config' module is loaded:
CFG = Self.OM.Load_Module( 'Config' )

---

```
def Load_Module( Self , Module = '' ) :
   
    if( modules ) :

        Module_Properties = OM.Register_Module( Self , Module )
        return( Module_Properties )
        
    else :
        print( f"[ ERROR ] No Module Specified !" )
```

The Load method is simple and directs the module to the method
'Register_Module' next.

---

```
def Register_Module( Self , Module ) :
            
    if( Module not in Self.Registered_Modules ) :
        print( f"[ MSG ] The Specified Module '{Module}' Is Not Registered !" )
    else :
        print( f"[ ERROR ] The Specified Module '{Module}' Is Already Registered !" )
        return Registered_Modules[ Modules ]
            
    Module_Descriptor = Module.split( "::" , -1 )[ -1 ]
  
    Module_FH = Module
    Module_FH = Module_FH.replace( '::' , '/' ) + '.py'

    Module_Instance = importlib.import_module( Module.replace( '::' , "." ) )

    Module_Methods = [ method_name for method_name in dir( Module_Instance )
    if callable(getattr( Module_Instance , method_name ) ) ]
       
    if( Module_Instance.OM_Manager == True ) :
        
        if( Module_Descriptor not in Module_Methods ) :
            print( f"[ ERROR ] The Constructor Of The Specified Module '{Module}' Could Not Be Found !" )
            exit( 0 )
        
        Module_Attributes = getattr( Module_Instance , Module_Descriptor )( )
    
    Self.Registered_Modules.update( { Module_Descriptor : Module_Attributes } )
    
    return( Module_Instance )
```

In the 'Register_Module' method I load the corresponding module and save the attributes
of the module in the global dictionary 'Registered_Modules' as an object ( Name : Attributes ).

---

---

After the steps shown above, the 'Config' file is loaded:

```
from OM import *

OM_Manager = True

class Config( ) :
    
    define __init__( Self ) :
        
        Self.Config_Entries = { }
        Config.Config_Loader( Self )

        print( Self.Test )
        
    def Config_Loader( Self ) :

        Self.Config_Entries.update( { "Probe" : "1234" } )
```

However, I still have a few open problems.

1. I initialize the Object Manager in the start script with 'Self.OM = OM( )'
   If I then load the config with 'CFG = Self.OM.Load_Module( 'Config' )',
   Python passes Self after all. So Self.OM should also be available?
   But a print in the config fails:

   print( Self.OM )

   Why is this variable missing?
2. Is the 'Register_Module' method correct? I basically want them
   Variables of the other program parts into an object in the global variable
   'Registered_Modules' so I can access it later from anywhere
   e.g. with :

   Config = OM.Registered_Modules[ 'Config' ]
3. I can't load another module in a subfile, e.g. B. Load 'Config' here:
   e.g. with :

   classConfig( ) :

   ```
    def __init__( Self ) :

        Self.Config_Entries = { }
        Config.Config_Loader( Self )

        OM.Load_Module( 'Config::Defaults' )
   ```

When loading the module 'Config::Defaults', the Object Manager only reports "No Module Specified"!

I hope that I explained my code clearly and hope that you
can help with my problems. I would also be happy for suggestions
to improve my program code.

Thanks very much !

Best regards
NumeroUnoDE

Comment: No experts here, who have experience with that ?

Comment: Not a reproducible example (`NameError: modules not defined`, `NameError: importlib not defined`, `AttributeError: Config has no attribute Test`) Also a typo (`define` should be `def`)

Comment: 1. Please clarify. Where you think does Python pass `Self`? 3. You didn't specify a module as `Load_Module` is an instance method which requires an instance passed to it (which goes into `Self`). If you call it like you do in your question, the module name goes into `Self` and `Module` will be an empty string

Comment: Hey, i would like to send you the code, but i guess, it's a little bit too complicated to post the whole scripts in the comments. Do you have an e - mail or something i can use ?

Comment: EDIT : Please get it from https://file.io/OZbFPwQa8mE2